# Добавление уникальных значений из массива в БД PHP

Tags: php

Задача: заполнить поле numbers только уникальными значениями, полученными при заполнении массива.

Вроде бы все сделал, но как организовать проверку при генерации чисел на уникальность. Нужно, чтобы значения, которые уже есть в полях, не добавлялись в БД

Вот весь код:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
{
    $array = rand(10000000,99999999);
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO test(number) VALUES (.$array.)");
    echo $array . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: 1. Уникальность лучше проверять на стороне БД, для этого служит [индекс UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique). 2. Если при вставке в БД число оказалось НЕ уникальным, то возникнет ошибка, которую можно обработать в PHP. 3. Чтобы вставка была быстрой, все это обернуть в транзакцию. PS. Для вставки случайных чисел PHP не нужен! Все можно сделать одним запросом без PHP

Comment: @TotalPusher *Если при вставке в БД число оказалось НЕ уникальным, то возникнет ошибка, которую можно обработать в PHP.* Зачем заведомо генерить ошибки-то? INSERT IGNORE отработает без ошибки. А вставка или дубликат, покажет affected rows.

Comment: @Akina, это на тот случай, если в обязательном порядке нужно вставит 10 уникальных значений. `affected rows` - так тоже можно, я лично предпочитаю  бросать и перехватывать исключения.

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
{
 $array = rand(10000000,99999999);
 $query= mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT IGNORE INTO test(number) VALUES ($array)");
 echo $array . '<br>';
}

 $result = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT number FROM `test`");
 echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($result);

вроде как дебаг показывает, что одинаковых нет, значит сработало, большое спасибо

Comment: @TotalPusher Мне это не кажется правильным. Ошибка - это свидетельство того, что что-то не в порядке. Тогда как в данном случае дублирование - это штатное и ожидаемое поведение безошибочного выполнения операции, просто параметры такие, что привели к дублированию... И оно должно обрабатываться в рамках нормального исполнения кода, а не как реакция на нештатную ситуацию.

Comment: *вроде как дебаг показывает, что одинаковых нет* Это случайность. Да, вероятность дублирования при заданных границах весьма невелика - но и не нулевая. Следовательно, возможность дублирования нельзя не учитывать, и её необходимо обрабатывать.

Comment: @Akina какая случайность если он сделал ровно по вашему собственному сценарию?

Comment: как все же сделать все правильно? недавно начал изучать php

Comment: @Ипатьев Случайность то, что "одинаковых нет". А мой сценарий вообще не влияет появление дубликатов, он только имхо делает логичным разделение выполнения на нормальное выполнение (генерация случайного числа, уже присутствующего в наборе - это НЕ ошибка!) и обработку нештатных ситуаций (соединение разорвалось, какой-то болван удалил таблицу и пр.).